# Problems in updating ubuntu

Tags: apt, updates

When i am running command `sudo apt-get update`, i am facing following problems :

```
W: Failed to fetch http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/vivid/InRelease  

W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

What can be the possible solution here?

Comment: Try again later. Probably something temporary with that mirror.

Answer (score 0):

Change your server location to Main Server and run the command `sudo apt-get update`. This helped in my case.